# Integrating Swagger-UI with Angular-8 Application

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, angular8, polyfills, swaggerhub

I want to integrate my Angular8 (8.2.0) Application with Swagger-UI (3.24.0) and I'm getting the below error:

_stream_writable.js:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (_stream_writable.js:57)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:4)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js (index.js:28)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
    at Object. (swagger-ui.js:8)
    at n (swagger-ui.js:1)
    at Object. (swagger-ui.js:1)
    at Object. (swagger-ui.js:1)

I believe this issue is related to Polyfills and related to Angular, SwaggerUI versions incompatibility. 

 I tried with Angular (7.2.0) and SwaggerUI (3.21.0) and it works perfectly fine.
For your reference, here is the link I followed for SwaggerUI (3.21.0) integrate with Angular (7.2.0)
https://github.com/agoncal/swagger-ui-angular6

Answer (score 1):

add this  code below in polyfills.ts

```
(window as any).process = { browser: true };
```